# PhantomJS bug in basic script

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, phantomjs, browser-automation

This is a script pretending to log in your google account (I've made). But obviously, that doesn't work. There is no particular objective here, but to make it work.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg);
};
page.open('https://google.com/', function() {
    page.injectJs('jquery-2.2.1.min.js');
    page.evaluate(function() {
        function include(arr,obj) { // those functions are not part of scraping
            return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
        }
        function add(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
        Array.min = function( array ){
            return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
        };
        function dofirst() {
            $('#gb_70').click();
            main(1, 0);
        }
        function dosecond() {
            document.getElementById('Email').value = 'myemail@gmail.com';
            $('#next').click();
            main(2, 0);
        }
        function dothird() {
            document.getElementById('Passwd').value = 'P4SSW0RD';
            $('#signIn').click();
            main(3, 0);
        }
        function dofourth() {
            L1 = ['test', 'test2', 'google'];
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                if (L1, 'google') {
                    console.log('SUCCESS!');
                }
            }
            main(4, 0);
        }   
        function dofifth() {
            $('.gb_b.gb_8a.gb_R').click()
            setTimeout(function(){$('#gb_71').click()}, 500);
            main(0, 5000);
        }
        function main(i, j) {
            if (i === 0) {
                console.log('launching 0');
                setTimeout(dofirst(), j); // connections
            }
            else if (i === 1) {
                console.log('launching 1');
                setTimeout(dosecond(), 5000);
            }
            else if (i === 2) {
                console.log('launching 2');
                setTimeout(dothird(), 5000);
            }
            else if (i === 3) {
                console.log('launching 3');
                setTimeout(dofourth(), 5000);
            } else if (i === 4) {
                console.log('launching 4');
                setTimeout(dofifth(), 5000);
            }
        }
        main(0, 5000);
    });
    console('super end');
    page.render('google.png');
});
```

At the end I get those errors :

```
CONSOLE: launching 0
CONSOLE: launching 1
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('Email').value = 'myemail@gmail.com'')

  undefined:7 in dosecond
  :22 in main
  :4 in dofirst
  :18 in main
  :29
  :30
```

I tried many ways and no one worked. I could make it work though with Python and selenium web driver (which was real love). But now the time has passed, and it has to be in javascript (to be completely DOM/jQuery... so Web compatible).

Can you help me please to make it work!

EDIT 1: by trying to capture a screenshot, it does save an empty PNG.

EDIT 2: I think that may be a hint, when I do phantomjs test.js, it takes a very long time to finally load and logs quickly everything...

EDIT 3: I changed document.get(...).value = 'blabla' to $('#id').val('blabla'); And now it prints

```
CONSOLE: launching 0
CONSOLE: launching 1
CONSOLE: launching 2
CONSOLE: launching 3
CONSOLE: SUCCESS!
CONSOLE: SUCCESS!
CONSOLE: SUCCESS!
CONSOLE: SUCCESS!
CONSOLE: SUCCESS!
```

However it should prints only one SUCCESS, and evidently capture still does not work.

Comment: I think `.value` is not a property of a DOM element in javascript. Are you trying to use `jQuery('#Email').val('myemail@gmail.com')` like in jQuery? What is the DOM type of element `Email`?

Comment: But why would it takes ages to load?

Comment: You were right about .value
Now it prints what I added in EDIT 3

Comment: "ages" like more than the 5 seconds you have in your timeout `main(0,5000)`?

Comment: Yes, it is about 30s.
I'll measure it.

Comment: The fact it prints 5 times is just logic... I'm stupid ...
However it cannot capture any screenshots

Comment: You have a loop to print the `SUCCESS` with a value of `i` that starts with 0 and ends with 5. That's you get 5 successes.

Comment: You have to use the callback `page.onLoadFinished()`. You're probably trying to write the PNG before the elements are rendered.

Comment: How can I use a callback in evaluate() so, after DOM scripting is done, it exits evaluate mode and capture the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For EDIT 1: trying to capture the screen

Check the status to make sure the page is loaded.

```
page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        // exit if it fails to load the page
        console.log(status);
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    else{
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: I accepted the answer as you have helped. However I have another problem.
My script have to run all the time with a loop as I have changed the script to do so in the question. However I get a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.` error and everything goes very fast, whereas it should do the thing all 5s. What is happening and how could we fix it?

Comment: You have an endless loop in your logic. The `dofifth()` function calls the main function with `0` and starts calling all the other functions all over again. I suggest restructing your code with phantomJS `waitFor`. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32502929/2519988

Comment: The logic is to have an endless loop.
I'd like to be able to launch every x minutes/seconds (anything) the script, which is structured as 5 functions called by a master one.

Comment: Then use javascript `setInterval()` not `setTimeout()`

Comment: But the interval must be dynamic (with a variable timeout, which changes everytimes)!

Comment: do that with a global variable.. that prevent the function from running if it's too early, and set the interval to run every 500ms for example.